# Java socket objectoutputstream multi-thread

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket, objectoutputstream

I'v got code which use multi-thread to send object to ServerSocket (currently localy, but in future in local net)

Used for sending object:

```
public class SocketToAdapter {

public static void writeObject(Object object) {
    try {

        give().writeUnshared(object);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

static ObjectOutputStream give() {
    Socket s = null;
    try {
        s = new Socket("localhost", 9990);
        s.setTcpNoDelay(true);
        return new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

main method:

```
SocketToAdapter soc = new SocketToAdapter();

    thread1.setSocket(soc);
    thread2.setSocket(soc);
    thread3.setSocket(soc);
    thread4.setSocket(soc);
    thread5.setSocket(soc);

    synchronized (valueExchanging) {
        synchronized (soc) {
            thread1.start();
            thread2.start();
            thread3.start();
            thread4.start();
            thread5.start();
        }
```

valueExchanging is a Object that is used to exchange data beetwen threads.

Run method from thread:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            curr = new Object(pair, RandomUtil.getRandomExchange(),
                    RandomUtil.getRandomTurn());
            //not important Business Logic.
                            int v1 = valueExchanger.getExchangeInTread()+1;
            int v2 = valueExchanger.getExchangeInTread()-100;
            curr = new Object(pair, BigInteger.valueOf(v1),
                    BigInteger.valueOf(v2));
                            //
            SocketToAdapter.writeObject(curr);
            valueExchanger.setExchangeInTread(v1);
            Thread.sleep(0, 1);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException iex) {
    }
}
```

That works but very slowly. Propably because I create Socket and ObjectOutputStream every time when is need. I try to create one Socket and one OOS and use it like this:

```
                   {
        Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 9990);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream()); }
```

and then

```
oos.writeUnshared(object); 
oos.flush(); 
oos.writeUnshared(object);
```

but if I try to reuse oos second time i get Software caused connection abort: socket write error. Doesnt matter how much thread i use.

What im need is possiblity to send many (e.g. 100k) object per second, any sugesstions?

on server side i do:

Serwer.java:

```
    ServerSocket ss;
public static void pre()throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ss = new ServerSocket(9990);
    }

public static Object start() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Object o = null;
    Socket s = ss.accept(); 
    while (!s.isClosed()) {
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        o = (Object) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
        s.close(); 
    }
    ss.close();
    return o;

}
```

"main method"

```
    while (true) { 

            try {
                Serwer.pre();
                Object o = Serwer.start();
                                    //im do somethink with that object o.
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why do you synchronize on soc when starting the threads? When using a resource from several threads, you have to synchronize on the resource. And keep synchronized blocks short. Or even try getting along without. Synchronization is a huge performance killer.

Comment: Currently is not a problem with synchronize (even if I use one thread without synchronized, performance suck).

Comment: You definitely have to bring more structure to your design. No offense, but try to not do too many things in one place...

Answer (score 1):

In the client it's opening a new TCP connection for every object that is sent.  This will kill performance as there is a large amount of overhead to establish a TCP connection.

From your code the server looks like it is closing the connection after handling a single object.  It also closes the `ServerSocket` after handling a single connection which doesn't seem like it would work at all.  Is the server code provided correct?  Is there another loop occurring in the server code that will start up another `ServerSocket`?

The best approach might be to have each client thread create its own `Socket` which each has a separate connection to the server.  If you are trying to push a lot of data and using multiple threads to achieve that then there is a good chance that the server will need multiple threads to handle the data.  These sockets should be created a single time and reused to send all of the objects.

On the server side you will want to create a proper multithreaded TCP server.  The general idea here is to create a single `SocketServer` and call its `accept()` method in a `while` loop.  For each `Socket` that is returned from `accept()` you will fire up a new thread to handle the request.  An example can be found here:  [Multithreaded Server using TCP in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784280/multithreaded-server-using-tcp-in-java)

Comment: i called "main method" there is a loop

Comment: You know that you can just loop over the accept() rather than over the whole serversocket creation?. You even could could handle multiple connections simultanoulsy spawning a Thread for each Socket you get by the next accept ...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it by using a simple Wrapper-Class for my Sockets.
The object of this class has to be present at any point where read/write actions are needed.

```
public class Sender implements Closeable 
{
  private final Socket sock;
  private final ObjectOutputStream out;
  private ObjectInputStream in = null;

  private final Object oLock = new Object();
  private final Object iLock = new Object();

  //optional
  public boolean isClosed(){
    return sock.isClosed();
  }

  //there is a better way to do this
  public Socket getSocket(){

    return sock;
  }

  //use this to send data
  public void send(Object o) throws IOException {
    synchronized (oLock){
        getOOS().writeObject(o);
    }
  }

  //use this to read data
  public Object get() throws IOException {
    synchronized (iLock){
        return getOIS().readObject();
    }
  }

  private ObjectOutputStream getOOS() {
    return out;
  }

  //not the best way... but wouldn't work otherwise
  private ObjectInputStream getOIS() throws IOException {
    if(in == null)
        in = new ObjectInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
    return in;
  }

  public Sender(Socket s) throws IOException {
    sock = s;
    out = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
    //in = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
    //getting the input and output stream gave me some weird deadlock
  }

  //optional
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return sock.toString();
  }

  //flush and close if sock is not yet closed
  @Override
  public void close() throws IOException {
    if(!sock.isClosed()){
        if(out != null)
            out.flush();

        sock.close();
    }
  }
}
```

This one works well and fast in client (Sender is the Socket connected to the Server) and 
server (Sender are the Sockets connected to the clients).

Hope this helps.

Greets roop

Answer (score 0):

Does you server at 9990 close the connection after reading an object, or is it failing ?

After this is sorted out, you can look at optimizing speed serialization using fast object serializers like [kryo](https://code.google.com/p/kryo/)

Answer (score 0):

i dont have experience in java sockets, but by the line s.setTcpNoDelay(true); i asume your program is using tcp to send the packets, try using udp instead. the tcp protocol is meant to garantee that the packet arrive to their destination, and to do this it has to verify integrity once they arrive. udp on the other hand does not do this, it only sends the packets and is not concerned about the integrity, that is why online multiplayer games use it.

Comment: how i can use UDP instead of TCP?

Comment: @user1055201 Thats a whole different story. Maybe this will help: http://systembash.com/content/a-simple-java-udp-server-and-udp-client/